# How long should I wait on recovering journal, Clearing, clean?

Tags: boot, data-recovery

After reverting to a legacy nvidia driver to access an old nvidia card, I rebooted.  Why reboot?  Because `nvidia-smi`, etc. won't work sometimes without a reboot.  However, the rebooting system never displayed anything so after a while I powered off, removed the old nvidia card and powered back up.  That's when I saw:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: recovering journal
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: Clearing orphaned inode 45095372 (uid=..., gid=125, mode=..., size=8192)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 4322067/122011648 files, 192736109/488031232 blocks
```

There it sits with no progress bar or any other indicate of progress.

How long should I wait?  (It's accessing an M.2 SSD.)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally wait five minutes at most, and if it still hangs there, you should probably press alt+F2. That'll give you a terminal. Some of my Ubuntu and Manjaro systems alike would hang on the screen you're describing whenever I installed a driver that wasn't working. So, I would have to use terminal commands to restore the correct drivers (if you have the binary for the unified drivers downloaded you can run `./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-xxx.xxx.xx` in the directory they're located in, or if you don't you can use the `ubuntu-drivers` utility).

Hope this is helpful!!

Comment: alt+F2 did nothing. Rebooted.  At GRUB menu pressed ENTER and immediately began pressing alt+F2 repeatedly to hopefully catch it in a state prior to the inactive state.  Then a message came up `[FAILED] Failed to start Advanced key-value store (delegate/public).`  That's a custom piece of software activated by `systemd` but even if it fails it shouldn't stop the boot.

Comment: I was able to get to the shell by selecting advanced options from the `GRUB` menu and selecting a recover kernel.  However `ubuntu-drivers` didn't permit me to go back to a newer driver when I executed `ubuntu-drivers install nvidia-driver-515`.  It just said "All the available drivers are already installed" as if I didn't know that driver was already installed BUT NOT ACTIVATED.

Comment: Next tried `apt reinstall nvidia-driver-515` but it failed due to no network.  So I followed this advice to activate the network and was able to execute the reinstall:  https://serverfault.com/a/975941 and I am now able to reboot the system to the normal GUI.